# Maximum step size as a scalar function on the domain

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

In `NDSolve` when solving a system of ODEs, one can control the maximum time step for the whole domain with `MaxStepSize`. But there are regions that, for varied reasons, one might desire a higher resolution. For example, near a shockwave front, or near the peak of some force function with a delta-like time dependence.

One could always do a piecewise `NDSolve` solution by stitching the solutions of ODEs run with different `MaxStepSize`, but if there already exists some way to control it with a function that depends on the domain of integration, that would become a much simpler task

Is there a way to control the max time step dynamically?

Comment: Please provide the code you are trying to execute (without the variable MaxStepSize), so that readers can better understand the problem.  Note that NDSolve typically reduces its step size below the specified maximum when needed for good resolution.

Comment: [Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html#568926686) may be of use to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate the suggestion in my comment, consider the trivial problem of a decaying exponential.

```
s10 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 2}, MaxStepSize -> 0.1];
```

The integration points taken by `NDSolve` are given by

```
x["Coordinates"] /. s10
(* {{{0., 0.000145167, 0.000290334, 0.00480762, 0.00932491, 0.0138422, 
      0.0280929, 0.0423435, 0.0565942, 0.0708448, 0.0993461, 0.127847, 
      0.156349, 0.18485, 0.213351, 0.300554, 0.387757, 0.454791, 
      0.521825, 0.588858, 0.655892, 0.722925, 0.789959, 0.889959, 
      0.989959, 1.08996, 1.18996, 1.28996, 1.38996, 1.48996, 1.58996, 
      1.68996, 1.78996, 1.88996, 1.94498, 2.}}} *)
```

The steps are small at first but eventually reach a maximum of `0.1`, as expected.

The following reduces `MaxStepSize` to `0.01` beyond `t = 1`.

```
ndssdata = First[NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{x'[t] == -x[t], x[0] == 1}, x[t], t]];
NDSolve`Iterate[ndssdata, 1];
ndss100 = First[NDSolve`Reinitialize[ndssdata, MaxStepSize -> 0.01, MaxSteps -> 1000]];
NDSolve`Iterate[ndss100, 2];
s100 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[ndss100];
Head[x[t] /. s100]["Coordinates"]
(* {{0., 0.0000918116, 0.000183623, 0.0047006, 0.00921757, 0.0137345, 
     0.0279852, 0.0422359, 0.0564865, 0.0707372, 0.0992385, 0.12774, 
     0.156241, 0.184743, 0.213244, 0.300446, 0.387648, 0.454681, 
     0.521714, 0.588746, 0.655779, 0.722812, 0.789844, 0.889844, 
     0.944922, 1., 1.00023, 1.00047, 1.00093, 1.0014, 1.00187, 1.00654, 
     1.01122, 1.01589, 1.02056, 1.03056, 1.04056, 1.05056, 1.06056, 
     1.07056, 1.08056, 1.09056, 1.10056, 1.11056, 1.12056, 1.13056, 
     1.14056, 1.15056, 1.16056, 1.17056, 1.18056, 1.19056, 1.20056, 
     1.21056, 1.22056, 1.23056, 1.24056, 1.25056, 1.26056, 1.27056, 
     1.28056, 1.29056, 1.30056, 1.31056, 1.32056, 1.33056, 1.34056, 
     1.35056, 1.36056, 1.37056, 1.38056, 1.39056, 1.40056, 1.41056, 
     1.42056, 1.43056, 1.44056, 1.45056, 1.46056, 1.47056, 1.48056, 
     1.49056, 1.50056, 1.51056, 1.52056, 1.53056, 1.54056, 1.55056, 
     1.56056, 1.57056, 1.58056, 1.59056, 1.60056, 1.61056, 1.62056, 
     1.63056, 1.64056, 1.65056, 1.66056, 1.67056, 1.68056, 1.69056, 
     1.70056, 1.71056, 1.72056, 1.73056, 1.74056, 1.75056, 1.76056, 
     1.77056, 1.78056, 1.79056, 1.80056, 1.81056, 1.82056, 1.83056, 
     1.84056, 1.85056, 1.86056, 1.87056, 1.88056, 1.89056, 1.90056, 
     1.91056, 1.92056, 1.93056, 1.94056, 1.95056, 1.96056, 1.97056, 
     1.98056, 1.99028, 2.}} *)
```

Beyond `t = 1`, the maximum step size is indeed 0.01.  Illustrated graphically,

```
pts = Transpose[{Flatten[Head[x[t] /. s100]["Coordinates"]], 
                 Flatten[Head[x[t] /. s100]["ValuesOnGrid"]]}];
ListPlot[pts, DataRange -> 2, AxesLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image]